# Why is filenotfound exception not getting printed/triggering in my log

Tags: java

So I have 2 methods whose code I am putting down below. First method calls the second method, the second method is responsible for opening a file reading its data and sending it to an dataoutputstream request variable.

My problem is that if the file doesnt exist in the folder, i am not able to print any stack trace, or information about the exception if the second method is called.

If however i un comment the commented lines in first method(which does the same thing) and do not call the second method at all, i am able to see the logs, stack trace and filenot found exception in my log file.

Can anyone suggest why this is happening ? I need to be able to get the file not found exception using even when the second method is called :

```
public void addBodySend(String metadata, File file, String pMode) throws Exception{           
    try{
        request = new DataOutputStream(httpConn.getOutputStream());
        String post_data = crlf+twoHyphens + boundary + crlf+"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"properties\""+crlf+crlf+metadata+crlf+twoHyphens+boundary+crlf;
        String fileName = file.getName();
        post_data = post_data + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\""+crlf+"Content-Type: application/octet-stream"+crlf+crlf;
        request.writeBytes(post_data);
        if(pMode == "LOCAL_DIR"){
            this.getLocalFile(file);
        }
        /*fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
        byte[] buffer;
        buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead=0;
        while((bytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
            request.write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
            request.flush();
        }
        request.writeBytes(crlf+twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + crlf);
        request.flush();*/
    }catch(Exception ex){
        this.sendStatus = false;
        ex.printStackTrace();
        log.writeln("Error while sending post request",0);
        for (StackTraceElement ste : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
            log.writeln(ste.toString(),0);
        }
    }finally{
        if(bufferedInputStream!=null){
            try{
            bufferedInputStream.close();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                log.writeln("Error closing bufferred input stream",0);
            }
        }  
        if(request!=null){
            try{
            request.close();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                log.writeln("Error closing post request",0);
            }
        }    
    }
}

public void getLocalFile(File file) {
    try{
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
        byte[] buffer;
        buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead=0;
        while((bytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
            request.write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
            request.flush();
        }
        request.writeBytes(crlf+twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + crlf);
        request.flush();   
        this.sendStatus = true;        
    }catch(Exception ex){
        this.sendStatus = false;
        ex.printStackTrace();
        log.writeln("Error while sending binary body",0);
        for (StackTraceElement ste : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
            log.writeln(ste.toString(),0);
        }
    }finally{
        if(bufferedInputStream!=null){
            try{
            bufferedInputStream.close();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                log.writeln("Error closing bufferred input stream",0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the second method actually called since you made it conditional with the if? Try debugging to see if and when the exception is thrown.

Comment: hmm, so i tried mutliple things and you are correct, whatever i have inside the if statement doesnt seem to execute, pMODE is String class, and I am trying to compare it to "LOCAL_DIR" i did print out the value of pMode before and seems to be the same, so I guess i am going wrong in the way i am comparing it ?

Comment: Because you aren't kogging it. You are only printing it. All you are logging is `"Error while sending post request"` and *another* stack trace. Log the *exception.*

Answer (score 1):

try changing the way you are comparing these strings `pMode` and `"LOCAL_DIR"`. Instead of

```
if(pMode == "LOCAL_DIR"){
     this.getLocalFile(file);
}
```

do

```
if("LOCAL_DIR".equals(pMode)){
      this.getLocalFile(file);
}
```

hope that helps

Comment: Yes i just did this, and that seems to work, what is the reasoning ? Maybe its tryng to compare the string pmode address to the value "LOCAL_DIR" and failing?

Comment: @Mickeyj26, `==` is used to verify if objects (in your case, strings) are the same in memory. Remember that Strings in java are immutable hence `"LOCAL_DIR"` and `pMode` will not refer to the same objects in memory (meaning `==` will be false ), Meanwhile the `.equals()` method actually returns true if both objects are identical.